# Visual Studio 2019 Uses Wrong Edge Browser Profile

Tags: visual-studio-2019

In VS 2019, I created a new Browser Profile for IIS Express by using the "Browse With ... " option.  In that dialog, I used "Add ..." and copied in the program and argument values from one of the profile shortcuts on my taskbar.

> Program: c:\Program Files(x86)...\msedge.exe
>
> Arguments: --profile-directory="Profile 2"

After creating that Browser Profile, I then set IIS Express to use my newly created browser profile as the default when launching my app.

However, when I press the IIS Express button to run my web app, the app launches in Edge -- but uses a generic profile instead of the specific profile that I pointed to with my arguments.

The Edge profile that I'm trying to use has specific extensions that help with debugging in the browser that I don't have installed in all my Edge profiles.

**Is there a way to get VS 2019 to launch the correct Edge Profile?**

Comment: Can you take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/a/381902/1320899)?

Comment: The link seems to deal with desktop shortcuts as opposed to VS 2019 Browser profiles.  My desktop shortcuts work flawlessly and open the correct Edge profile.

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid idea but try copying the cmdline from the shortcut and paste to VS and see if it works

Comment: Not a stupid idea at all; however, I tried that and that didn't help.